# WinUI 3 TemplateStudio Read from local settings using the LocalSettingsService

Tags: c#, winui-3, windows-template-studio

i am using TemplateStudio for WinUi3 to create my app. Now I want to Read my local settings using the ILocalSettingsService integrated by the TemplateStudio but i get an error.
Here's my code:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var notifications = _settingsService.ReadSettingAsync<String>("notifiacations");
    var notificationsSound = _settingsService.ReadSettingAsync<String>("notifications.sound");

    if (notifications != null && notificationsSound != null)
    {
        if (notifications.Result.ToString() == "on")
        {
            NotificationToggle.IsOn = true;

        }
        else
        {
            NotificationToggle.IsOn = false;
        }

        if (notificationsSound.Result.ToString() == "on")
        {
            NotificationSoundToggle.IsOn = true;

        }
        else
        {
            NotificationSoundToggle.IsOn = false;

        }
    }
}
```

And the error:

`System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."` on this line of my code:

`var notifications = _settingsService.ReadSettingAsync<String>("notifiacations");`

I've already tried to leave the <string> but that didnt work

Comment: It is because `_settingsService` is not initliazed. How are you trying to initialize it? Dependency injection?

Comment: This is my code:

using WinTube.Contracts.Services;

private readonly ILocalSettingsService _settingsService;

Comment: Says so in the constructor do you have something like `public className(ILocalSettingsService localSettingsService){ _settingsService = localSettingsService;` }

Comment: How is `_settingsService` being set/initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the service from the DI container.

Try adding this line the page's constructor:

```cs
_settingsService = App.GetService<ILocalSettingsService>();
```

Then you'll be able to get the value:

```cs
private async void SettingsPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var notifications = await _settingsService.ReadSettingAsync<string>("notifications");
}
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this but now if I execute this part of the code my app just crahes and the page doesnt load at all.

string notifications = _settingsService.ReadSettingAsync<string?>("notifications").Result;

Comment: Instead of `Result`, just use `asycn` and `await`. Check my updated answer.